# Best way to reach all properties of an element in a UserControl from MainWindow.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to this so I hope my question is not foolish.

Let say there is a simple UserControl (call it MyUC) like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUC.MyUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyUC"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="311" Height="150">

  <Grid>
    <Label x:Name="_lbl1" Width="104" Height="26" Margin="13,23,0,0"/>
    <Label x:Name="_lbl2"  Width="104" Height="26" Margin="13,53,0,0"/>
  <Grid/>
<UserControl/>
```

If I understand correctly, if I want to be able to reach properties of these elements (E.g. content of the Labels) in this UserControl (MyUC) from the MainWindow.xaml, i would have to add these properties in MyUC.xaml.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty Label_1_ContentProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("Label_1_Content", typeof(string), typeof(MyUC));

Public string Label_1_Content
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(Label_1_ContentProperty); }
  set { SetValue(Label_1_ContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty Label_2_ContentProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("Label_2_Content", typeof(string), typeof(MyUC));

Public string Label_2_Content
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(Label_2_ContentProperty); }
  set { SetValue(Label_2_Content_2_Property, value); }
}
```

add this binding to _lbl1 and _lbl2 content in the MyUC.xalm

```
<Label x:Name="_lbl1" Width="104" Height="26" Margin="13,23,0,0"
       Content="{Binding Label_1_Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                 AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUC}}}"/>

<Label x:Name="_lbl2" Width="104" Height="26" Margin="13,53,0,0"
       Content="{Binding Label_2_Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                 AncestorType={x:Type local:MyUC}}}"/>
```

and then those label properties are reachable and can be set from MainWindow.xalm like this

```
<control:MyUC Label_1_Content="This is the Label _lbl1 in the UserControl"
              Label_2_Content="This is the Label _lbl2 in the UserControl"/>
```

but I think this is not a good way to do because if there are more than a few properties in a UserControl I need 
to reach, then a lot of those dependency properties will be needed.

My question is: Is it possible to do it more simple and use each labels (_lbl1 and _lbl2) own properties directly and be able to do in MainWindow.xaml something like this

```
<control:MyUC _lbl1.Content="This is the Label _lbl1 in the UserControl"
              _lbl2.Content="This is the Label _lbl2 in the UserControl"/>
```

and how should be done in that case or if that is not possible how should I do it then?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want to use CodeBehind or the MVVM pattern?

Comment: If you have a lot of identical controls in a simple layout (e.g. all Labels with same size, stacked vertically or horizontally), you may better use an ItemsControl.

Comment: What you are doing is correct, the point in a `UserControl` is exactly for this kind of scenario, you are creating a reusable **group** of controls. It's much better to create a **single** `UserControl` with lots of **dependency properties** than to keep repeating yourself over and over.

Comment: Mike Eason: I understand the reusability vs repeating and that is why I want to be able to do like _lbl1.anyproperties and _lbl2.anyproperties if it is possible..

Comment: Rom: Right now I am using CodeBehind.

Comment: Clemens: I will look up that ItemsControl you wrote about.

Comment: It looks as you're violating encapsulation here. You should treat UserControl as a single piece of functionality and design its interface (i.e. publicly available properties and methods) in the way that their signatures would not change upon any change in user control's internals.
I seriously doubt you need to have every and all control's properties exposed externally. So, the best approach would be to define whatever is really worth exposing, add properties or dependency properties to UserControl and using binding to self in xaml to make everything work as expected.

Comment: AlexSeleznyov: So if I understand correct this <control:MyUC Label_1_Content="This is the Label _lbl1 in the UserControl"
              Label_2_Content="This is the Label _lbl2 in the UserControl"/> is not violating encapsulation 
     but this one <control:MyUC _lbl1.Content="This is the Label _lbl1 in the UserControl"
              _lbl2.Content="This is the Label _lbl2 in the UserControl"/> dose. Right?